# I want to make a video game based off of Dungeons and Dragons. How much am I legally permitted to use?

Tags: publishing, intellectual-property

I want to make a video game based off of Dungeons and Dragons. It'll be a top-down RPG with similar battle and class mechanics. But I've been planning out more, and seeing how much I'm copying. How much am I legally permitted to use? I am awayer of the SRD, but don't understand it fully. Is it like a book of what I'm allowed to use?

Comment: Questions about playing and developing video games are specifically off topic here.  I think there's another Stack where they're very much on topic.  Meanwhile, you might want to take the [Tour] and read through the [FAQ] to get a better handle on how Stack Exchange sites work and what we ask and answer on this one.

Comment: If you're concerned about legal issues because you're actually planning to make a game, you need to ask an actual lawyer for advice, not some random people on the internet :)

Comment: Have you read the [Wizards of the Coast's Fan Content Policy](https://company.wizards.com/en/legal/fancontentpolicy)?  You may also want to see related questions like "[What legal issues will I have with copying themes and ideas from existing RPG's?](/questions/73791)" and "[Is it legal to design and publish a game with D&D's ability scores?](/questions/78093)".

Comment: I disagree with the closing of this question. Yes, it’s for the purpose of developing a video game, but it’s as much about video game development as someone asking what brand of chips are best at an RPG table, or “what’s the best gear for programming on a boat?” is on-topic at Stack Overflow. This is fundamentally a question about the licenses around an RPG, which **is** on-topic here—the fact that they want to use those licenses for a video game is irrelevant. As MikeQ demonstrates, we have reasonable expertise on this. (That said, I agree with Erik that you cannot rely on our answers alone.)

Comment: As for other Stacks that might take this, there are both [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) and [Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/) Stacks. However, I don’t believe either is likely to be as familiar with Wizards of the Coast’s licenses as we are. And being on-topic elsewhere doesn’t automatically make anything off-topic here.

Comment: @Erik Before going to sale, or investing significant time and/or money on the project, yes, one absolutely must speak with a lawyer. However, it isn’t entirely unreasonable to start with a place such as this to get either “if you are very, very careful, this is possible,” vs. “no way, no how, don’t even waste the time or money asking a lawyer.” (I do not, off-hand, know which of those is accurate.)

Comment: Even if it's topical, the question is unclear and needs more details before it can be answerable. What are the "similar battle and class mechanics"?  What part of the SRD doesn't the querent understand, and how is that relevant to the question?  What research have they done on existing video games with such mechanics?

Comment: Right now, it's a biiiit broad for Law.SE. I think Law.SE could try to answer _specific_ questions about what the OGL allows, but the answer to "How much am I legally permitted to use?" is just "exactly as much as the license allows" which isn't really a useful/specific answer.

Comment: If there are noticeable similarities between your combat system and the DnD one, we also _really_ need to know which edition of DnD you're talking about before we can answer.  The license 3rd edition and 3.5 were released under is very different than 4th edition's, I found to my detriment.